# Kubuntu 18.04 - Fatal Error on X server when using LibreWriter - gpu hang

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, freeze, system, gpu

I am unable to use LibreWriter for more than a couple of minutes. Every now and then the X Server seems to freeze (see syslog and kernel los below) because the gpu hang? As far as I can tell, that problem only occurs when using LibreWriter. By now I have no problems with any other application like LibreCalc or others.

The system just freezes - it takes like a minute and then I am thrown at the login screen of Kubuntu. After login the applications are closed and I need to restore the LibreWriter file (which does not always work as it should).

I am not too familar with that logs but I can read that the GPU might hang? and because of that the X server crashes or something? I use the internal gpu of my i5 6600k, Asus Strix Z270 Gaming mainboard.

I would appreciate every hint and help to get rid of this problem.

The clock was 10:32 when it system freezed.
Syslog:

```
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]: Creating the cache for:  "applications:libreoffice-writer.desktop"
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]: Already in database?  true
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]:       First update :  QDateTime(2018-06-26 20:02:17.000 CEST Qt::TimeSpec(LocalTime))
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]:        Last update :  QDateTime(2018-11-30 09:52:48.000 CET Qt::TimeSpec(LocalTime))
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]: After the adjustment
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]:      Current score :  8.8479
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]:       First update :  QDateTime(2018-06-26 20:02:17.000 CEST Qt::TimeSpec(LocalTime))
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]:        Last update :  QDateTime(2018-11-30 09:52:48.000 CET Qt::TimeSpec(LocalTime))
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]: Interval length is  0
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]:          New score :  9.8479
Nov 30 10:29:37 ruphus-desk org.kde.ActivityManager[1891]: ResourceScoreUpdated: "2d4e9c94-b175-4f6d-8c7d-a293643d8881" "org.kde.krunner" "applications:libreoffice-writer.desktop"
Nov 30 10:32:50 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4632.093628] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:32:54 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4636.125607] asynchronous wait on fence i915:kwin_x11[6744]/1:299e timed out
Nov 30 10:32:54 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4636.125620] asynchronous wait on fence i915:kwin_x11[6744]/1:299e timed out
Nov 30 10:32:58 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4640.061736] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:33:06 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4648.093799] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:33:14 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4656.061905] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:33:22 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4664.061988] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:33:23 ruphus-desk org.kde.runners.baloo[1891]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Nov 30 10:33:23 ruphus-desk at-spi-bus-launcher[2056]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Nov 30 10:33:23 ruphus-desk at-spi-bus-launcher[2056]:       after 1483 requests (1483 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Kernel log:

```
Nov 30 10:32:50 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4632.093628] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:32:54 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4636.125607] asynchronous wait on fence i915:kwin_x11[6744]/1:299e timed out
Nov 30 10:32:54 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4636.125620] asynchronous wait on fence i915:kwin_x11[6744]/1:299e timed out
Nov 30 10:32:58 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4640.061736] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:33:06 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4648.093799] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:33:14 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4656.061905] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:33:22 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4664.061988] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Nov 30 10:33:42 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4683.863464] kauditd_printk_skb: 87 callbacks suppressed
Nov 30 10:33:42 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4683.863465] audit: type=1400 audit(1543570422.229:3969): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi///usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=9720 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov 30 10:33:42 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4683.863788] audit: type=1400 audit(1543570422.229:3970): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi///usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback" pid=9720 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov 30 10:33:42 ruphus-desk kernel: [ 4683.866277] audit: type=1400 audit(1543570422.233:3971): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi///usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=9721 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar crashes (based on dmesg output) and found a post somewhere that mentioned adding 'i915.enable_rc6=0' to /etc/default/grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.

After that I haven't seen any more crashes.

Comment: Could you/anyone explain what this does?